# Extract text from string based on value of a cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, string, extract

I have a workbook with a series of sheets that I need to run a code to resolve the data.

I have one worksheet with a list of "codes" and another sheet that has cells that will include a string of codes.

I am trying to create a macro that allows me to reference a code in sheet1 A1, and then look through B:B in sheet2 and copy the row if the code appears in the string

I am a novice VBA user and have tried googling a few things and I'm not having any luck.

Edit:

I have managed to get something that does copy the data through, but there seems to be an issue in the For loop as all lines are copied in, not just the lines that match. Code below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("MASTER LIST").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("VALIDATED LIST").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("VALIDATED LIST").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("MASTER LIST").Range("E1:E" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = InStr(Worksheets("MASTER LIST").Range("E1:E" & I).Value, Worksheets("TRANSPOSED DATA NO SPACES").Range("B1:B" & J)) > 1 Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("VALIDATED LIST").Range("A" & J + 1)
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Further Edit:

I want to be able to use the list of feature codes and look them up in the master list.

[image: I want to be able to use the list of feature codes and look them up in the master list.]

[image: Second Image]

If the VBA code finds the feature code in the strings in the master list, then I need to copy the row and paste it into a blank sheet that will be called validated list.

Comment: Can you share an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work, just remove duplicates on sheet3 after running. This is a double loop in which, for each cell in column B of sheet 2, the macro will check all values from sheet1 Column A. You will see duplicate lines in the end, but it doesn't matter right? all you need is remove dupes

```
Sub IvanAceRows()

Dim cell2 As Range, cells2 As Range, cell1 As Range, cells1 As Range
Dim lastrow2 As Long, lastrow1 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long

Set ws1 = Worksheets("USAGE CODES")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("MASTER LIST")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("VALIDATED LIST")

lastrow1 = ws1.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = ws2.cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Set cells1 = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow1)
Set cells2 = ws2.Range("B1:B" & lastrow2)

iii = 1

For ii = 1 To lastrow2

    For i = 1 To lastrow1

            If InStr(1, ws2.cells(ii, 2), ws1.cells(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
                ws2.cells(ii, 2).EntireRow.Copy
                ws3.Activate
                ws3.cells(iii, 1).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial
                iii = iii + 1
            End If

    Next i

Next ii

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub look_up_copy()
Dim last_row As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim Cells As Range

last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set Cells = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1:B" & last_row)

For Each cell In Cells:
    If cell.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

You didn't say anything about wanting to paste, but if you do then just insert it after the copy line.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your spreadsheet, I assumed all of your 'codes' are listed in Column A in sheet1, and all of those code strings are also in sheet2 in column B. my code allows u to find each string from sheet1 in Column B of sheet2. Once found, it will be pasted into Sheet3 starting from the 2nd row.

```
Sub IvanfindsRow()

Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim Code As String
Dim search As Range


lastrow1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Select
For i = 1 To lastrow1

Code = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
Set search = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B22").Find(what:=Code, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not search Is Nothing Then
            search.EntireRow.Copy
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial
            Else 'do nothing
        End If

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I can share my workbook with you on here. This works great when the "code" is in a cell on its own, but my head ache come in when it is part of a string with other codes in the same cell.

Comment: that shouldn't be a big problem, how do you recognize the codes within a certain cell? Does it have a pattern?u can do a screenshot of ur worksheet and share it here.

Comment: I have tried to add images to the main part of the post, hopefully you can see them

Comment: I'm going to eat dinner now, when I come back I will work on this and delete this message. But most likely someone else would have probably already posted an answer by then. see you. For now, you can remove the 'lookat:=xlwhole from that code and rerun